# Powershell hashtable keys with special characters

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble trying to access a hashtable with a / in the key.  In my case the keys are mime types, and a simple example of the hashtable looks like:

```
PS H:\> $h

Name                           Value                                                                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                                                                         
application/pdf                {application/pdf, application/pdf}
```

When I try to do access by the Key name, I am not getting any results:

```
   PS H:\> $h."application/pdf"

   _______________________________________
   PS H:\> $h["application/pdf"]

   _____________________________________________
   PS H:\>
```

What is going on here, and how to I use this key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion the Key is not a string but an object? I have no problems getting the value both ways:

```
PS> $h=@{'application/pdf'='application/pdf'}
PS> $h["application/pdf"]    
application/pdf

PS> $h."application/pdf"
application/pdf
```

Comment: That was it, I'd missed an "-AsString" on the Group-Object -AsHashtable that was creating the hash in the first place.  This is interesting too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449961/array-object-keys-for-hashtables-in-powershell

Comment: Could you @slipsec elaborate on why it did not work for you. How was your hashtable created exactly?

Comment: Sorry, no... it was 3 years ago, and I can't recall.